# How to expand content upon clicking the text in the Blogger interface?

Tags: html, blogger

I am using blogger to organize my thoughts. I am arranging raw thoughts in a page, where many thoughts are placed under the related heading. As the thought list is increasing, I am not able to have an overview, for the exploration or decision I am taking, to progress.

I searched everywhere on this, and tried to include certain code, but failed to get the result. As I don't know anything about web designing languages, it has become difficult to have this flexibility. What should I do now in blogger? Which code should I place, to get this hide/show ability?

Comment: Does a clickable/link button that shows a spoiler work?

Comment: @easterlyirk: Thank you for the reply. I want something like that in amazon books interface, viz. in the book description of the book, if we click on "read more", it expands. But, I haven't had experience on the spoiler thing.

Comment: So some blue text saying "read more" or "show" works?

Comment: @easterlyirk: Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add this code (it's already wrapped in `<script>` tags for you) to your website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function HideContent(d) {
        document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
    }
    function ShowContent(d) {
        document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
    }
    function ReverseDisplay(d) {
        if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
        else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
    }
</script>
```

Next, add a `<div>` with a unique id (what you choose is up to you, just keep the id the same throughout the whole code).  Like this:

```
<div id="uniquename" style="display:none;">
    <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Finally, add an `<a>` element (short for attribute, basically means clickable text). This will create (by default blue) text saying "Read More".  When clicked, this expands the div.

```
<a href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename')">Read more</a>
```

For text that hides the div:

```
<a href="javascript:HideContent('uniquename')">Show less</a>
```

And for code that toggles the div:

```
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename')">Read more/less</a>
```

To change the color of the links (even though this isn't the best way), do this:

```
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename')" style="color:green;">Read more/less</a>
```

You can replace "green" with most colors or a hex code.

Comment: It is working! But, I am trying re-arrangements, like having the content expand below by clicking on a text placed above it. I will be back soon..

Comment: Thank you very much, I have got the desired result.

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer Glad it helped!

Comment: Is there any way of reducing code in the last three sections (leaving the first) to just a simple syntax? Now I am collapsing the large texts, it is taking lot of time. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer you mean it is taking a long time to expand the div? No, not really. That means the div might be too big, try breaking it up into multiple divs.

Comment: No, the code is working properly, the division expansion is quick; what I meant was that, I have many headings (around 52 in one page) with texts below them to be expanded; I haven't yet completed one page now. There are two more such pages yet to be organized. Collapsing all these is taking more time. So, I wanted to know, if there is a way to reduce the code to somewhat like this [read more][abcd], by increasing first code.

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer sorry, no. I understand what you mean, but there isn't really a shorter way unless blogger has a builtin-one, and I don't think it does.

Comment: In the mobile version of the blog, division is not expanding. Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer most likely the mobile app/browser doesn't support JS. There's nothing I can do about that except possibly tell you to update it.

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of the expandable links?

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer yes, I'll edit my answer explaining how. You should probably also work on learning CSS, I can't help much with that.